# Copying field in from one event to other in logstash

Tags: logstash

Can anyone tell me if I can copy a field from one event to another in Logstash based on a unique_key present in both the events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

You can use the [`aggregate` filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html)  for exactly this purpose.

Exercise caution if you are processing very large volumes of data or if the matching documents do not arrive in close proximity to one another.